# How can I join all these armatures while keeping the different animations of all bones?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

I want to create an animated pitcrew mod for a game but unfortunately it doesn't support having multiple rigged objects in the same file.

I got these 4 lads here, all having different armatures with different animations.
[image]

I want to join every armature into one but keeping the individual animations. Would this be possible?

Thanks in advance for your help!